# Where is radar.js?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, chart.js, jslink

[In this blog](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/convert-sharepoint-list-view-to-radar-chart-using-client-side-rendering-and-char/), the author states to use the following JSLink shortcut:

~site/siteassets/jquery-1.12.1.min.js|~site/siteassets/Chart.js|~site/siteassets/Radar.js

I downloaded the 2.9.3 chart.js.zip [here](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/releases/download/v2.9.3/Chart.js.zip).

I unzipped it, but can't find any file called "Radar.js".

Questions:

1. Is this shortcut reference still valid/correct?
2. Where is radar.js?
3. Should I expect this entire thing to work on an Online version of SharePoint, or will it only work in a locally hosted instance?

Comment: Welcome. You should write to the author of the tutorial and ask why the file is missing. "where" in this case not related to StackOverflow. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Radar.js is your jslink script the author shared.Means save the "Full code" as Radar.js and host in siteassets library.